# Product/Method to merge multiple PDF files and serve as one file dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf

Are there any free products or ninja methods to merge PDFs in a commercial application and serve as one PDF for the end user?  I see iTextSharp does this, but we cannot comply with the GPL license and I was looking for a free method before a paid method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run into the same licensing problem with iTextSharp. My interim solution: Usage of the old version still licensed under LGPL:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/itextsharp-4.1.6

Merging PDFs is no problem with this release

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/SimplePdfMerger.aspx

Comment: Where can I find the licensing info for that version?

Answer (score -1):

We use [CETE Dunamic PDF Merger](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/) here. Not bad. But not free.